# How to reset the search bar location in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

After a sudden shutdown to my computer (electricity off), the Outlook 365 pro 2016 search bar has changed to the top of the window as shown in the photo.

I need to get it back to be next to "read & unread" messages. I did rest the view and searched everywhere in the outlook with no luck to get it worked,

I performed online & quick repairing and still the same issue.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatelly it's a new **mandatory** "feature" now in Outlook, without the option to reset the search bar position back :(

If you search internet for [outlook return instant search bar to its original place site:answers.microsoft.com](http://outlook%20return%20instant%20search%20bar%20to%20its%20original%20place%20site:answers.microsoft.com), you will find that many users are *very* upset by this unpleasant change, too, but that there is no solution at the moment. It cannot be moved back any more by unchecking "Coming soon".

The only soothing fact might be that you may use <kbd>F3</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) to jump instantly into the search bar.

Answer (score -3):

You can [create a new profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d) in case some personal settings are corrupted.

If not, some registered settings may be broken during shutdown, reset Outlook related settings in Registry:

Find this path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook

Rename it to Outlook-1

Restart Outlook.

(**Note:** this will reset all Outlook settings, such as profile/view settings. You need to reconfigure your email account after this.)

Comment: thank you, i tried your solution, it created a new profile but didn`t fix the issue unlikely.

Comment: If issue continues after renaming Outlook registry, I think the quickest way is to reinstall Office

Comment: unlikely i had to reinstall office again and it fixed the issue.

Comment: So glad to see that your issue was fixed

Comment: It is not a solution any more. The new "feature" is already officially part of Outlook.

Answer (score -3):

The simple fix is just to turn off 'Coming Soon' future right on top, restart outlook and wolla issue fixed

Comment: Shouldn't it be viola!!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work any more, this idiotic new position is a mandatory feature as of now :(

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Well, shouldn't it be *cello* instead? :) The word is **voilà** (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voil%C3%A0). **Viola** is a musical instrument (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola).

Comment: @HonzaZidek... No, and I know English can be weird like this sometimes but what I wrote is definitely accurate in English... https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voila and thus more specifically https://i.imgur.com/1BPfB3L.png

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Please read again what you have written :) For sure "viola" is not an alternative spelling of "voilà". It is simply a musical instrument. Slightly bigger than the violin, tuned one quint lower. I am not talking about the missing accent, but about your swapped letters "i" and "a".

Comment: Ah, lol... yep, you got me there, wow! That is too funny lmao! Let's go Trumpet instead. Thank you @HonzaZidek Am I human or am I alien and perfection. It even got an upvote, so that is too funny, I didn't even notice after looking at it deeper once you said something.... No saxophone and drums instead!